# Symfony FOSUserBundle Override Templates Not Working

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a problem about Symfony FOSUserBundle Override Templates.

I tried

> Create A Child Bundle And Override Template

way in [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html) documentation.

I can override Controllers with this way but still can't override templates. I found a [github demo](https://github.com/HuddleHouse/symfony-demo/tree/override-templates) about it and we have just 1 difference.

But my project is FOSUserBundle Controllers returning like ;

```
return $this->render('@FOSUser/Security/login.html.twig', $data);
```

In his project FOSUserBundle Controllers returning like ;

```
return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig', $data);
```

I want to ask :

-If I change it manually and then if there is update for this bundle would it change it back ..

-When installing FOSUserBundle for my project I want it to be like in his project's. How can i achieve it ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the vendor's controller. If you want to change any code in FOSUserBundle controllers, you have to override it too. Which bundle overriding the FOSUserBundle, you can create own controllers in that bundle. After that you can use that for your own strategy.

Sample Bundle: https://github.com/mertoksuz/symfony2-rest/tree/master/src/RestApi/UsersBundle

Check this UsersBundle.

Thank you.

Comment: I can override Controller and I can write own return code but I don't want it. Because I think still it is too manually.. If you look to the github repo , download and run "composer install" vendor files will be download like my want way. There is a parameter or something else that makes it different...

Thank you for answer..

Edit: I downloaded your symfony-2-ticket-system repo and run composer install. And look at your vendor FOSUserBundle controllers too ;

return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig', $data);

Why my controller is different .. ?

Comment: which version of FOSUserBundle ?. anyway this is your problem. https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/commit/dd1fa8fbb6df2d6037c136cc2b29a568f250069e